# how to Query the Custom Sort Order that was stored in a different table?

Tags: sql

Suppose I got a table Tbl1 (C1, C2, C3)

**C1-C2-C3**

A - 2 - 6

N - 6 - 7

C - 9 - 4

K - 3 - 5

& another table OrderOfTbl1 (C1, customOrder int)

**C1 - customOrder**

K - 1

N - 2

C - 3

A - 4

Now, I can do all sort of query on Tbl1 & the result can be any order

N - 6

A - 2

K - 3

So, how to make this result sorted as the Order stated in OrderOfTbl1 table?

I don't wanna to do the Join between these 2 tables, I prefer the "Order by Case .... Then ...." solution since it is more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a join is your best choice. However, if you want to avoid joining explicitly, you can do this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 t
ORDER BY (SELECT customOrder FROM orderoftbl1 ot WHERE t.c1 = ot.c1)
```

The requirement for this to work is that the `SELECT` inside `ORDER BY` returned a scalar.

Comment: Your query is perfect, it very simple & elegant. Thax u very much

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is by using a join:

```
select t.*
from table1 t left outer join
     orderoftbl1 ot
     on t1.c1 = ot.c1
order by ot.customerOrder
```

You can use a `case` statement when you have constants:

```
select *
from table1
order by (case when c1 = 'K' then 1
               when c1 = 'N' then 2
               . . .
          end)
```

But that defeats the purpose of having another table.

What do you mean by "solution since it is more natural"?  What makes one SQL statement "more natural" than another?

You could possibly do what you want using a correlated subquery in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from table1 t1
order by (select customerOrder from orderoftbl1 ot where ot.c1 = t1.c1)
```

However, almost no one would consider this "simpler" or "more natural" than the version with the `join`.  In fact, some databases may not support the correlated subquery in the `order by` clause.  Prior to this answer, I certainly have never written such SQL.

Comment: suppose the Tbl1 was join with many different tables & if we use solution 1, then query many be complicated

Comment: I want to have a simple query, like "Select * from tbl1 order by (select C1, customOrder from OrderOfTbl1) something like that but i don't know the query

Comment: if u have to order a lot of fields: order by c1,c2,c3.c4....
then it will be too complicated if u use Left join